# WP_query with ajax filter not working with input fields

Tags: wp-query, ajax, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having trouble with my query when using ajax to filter the posts.
I have a page where the posts of post type 'activiteiten' are loaded when the start_date custom field has today's date or a date in the future. There are 3 filter fields added:

- input field for location: this should check if the entered term is part of the custom field for location
- dropdown field (select) with custom taxonomy (eventtype)
- input field for date

The taxonomy dropdown filter works fine, but I can't seem to combine it with the other filters.

**Page template:**

```
<div class="details__section activity__listing">
<div class="container">
    <div class="query_filter row">
        <div class="filter-block col">
            <label for="search-activities">Zoek op gemeente</label>
            <input type="text" name="search" class="search-activities" id="search-activities" placeholder="<?php _e('Zoek op gemeente', 'omg') ?>">
        </div>

        <?php $types = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'eventtype')); ?>
        <?php if (!empty($types)) { ?>
            <div class="filter-block col">
                <label for="cat-select">Type activiteit</label>
                <select class="filter-dropdown" id="type-select" name="type-select">
                    <option value="" selected=""><?php _e('Alle activiteiten', 'omg') ?></option>

                    <?php foreach($types as $type) { ?>
                        <option value="<?= $type->slug; ?>"><?= $type->name; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <div id="myDatepicker" class="filter-block col datepicker">
            <div class="date">
                <label for="date-select"><?php _e('Datum', 'omg') ?></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/jjjj" class="date-select" id="date-select" aria-describedby="date-description">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    $activities = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'activiteiten',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key'  => 'start_date',
        'meta_value' => date('Ymd'),
        'meta_compare' => '>=',
        'meta_type' => 'DATE',
    ));
    ?>

    <?php if($activities->have_posts()) { ?>
        <div class="project-tiles">
            <?php while($activities->have_posts()) { $activities->the_post(); $f = get_fields();
                include 'template-parts/activiteit-detail.php';
            } ?>
        </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
function filterActivities(e) {
    $(".project-tiles").addClass("loading");
    var location = $("#search-activities").val() // zoek op gemeente
    , date = $("#date-select").val() // datum
    , type = $("#type-select").val(); // Type activiteiten
    e && (datum = location = null,
    $("#search-activities, #date-select, #type-select").val("")),
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            action: "filter_projects",
            locatie: location,
            datum: date,
            eventtype: type,
        },
        success: function(e) {
            $(".project-tiles").html(e),
            $(".project-tiles").removeClass("loading")
        }
    })
  }
```

**Functions.php:**

```
function filter_projects() {
    $location = $_POST['locatie'];
    $date = $_POST['datum'];
    $convertedDate = date('Ymd', strtotime($date));
    $type = $_POST['eventtype'];

    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

    if (isset($location)) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'locatie',
            'value' => $location,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

    if (isset($date)) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $convertedDate,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        );
    } else {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        );
    }

    $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
    if (isset($type)) {
        $tax_query[] =  array(
            'taxonomy' => 'eventtype',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $type,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        );
    }  

    $ajaxposts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'activiteiten',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    ));

    $response = '';

    if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
      while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) { $ajaxposts->the_post();
        $response .= get_template_part('template-parts/activiteit-detail');
      }
    } else {
      $response = 'empty';
    }

    echo $response;
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_projects', 'filter_projects');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_projects', 'filter_projects');
```

If I check the variables inside my function ($date, $type, $location), they're filled with the correct information, but it looks like something goes wrong when I try to combine these 3 filters inside the ajax query.

If I dump the complete query, I have this:

```
object(WP_Query)#16580 (52) {
["query"]=>
array(6) {
["post_type"]=>
string(12) "activiteiten"
["posts_per_page"]=>
int(-1)
["order"]=>
string(3) "ASC"
["orderby"]=>
string(14) "meta_value_num"
["meta_query"]=>
array(3) {
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "locatie"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "grem"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(10) "start_date"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "19700101"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(1) "="
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "DATE"
  }
}
["tax_query"]=>
array(2) {
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(9) "eventtype"
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "slug"
    ["terms"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["operator"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
  }
}
}
["query_vars"]=>
array(68) {
["post_type"]=>
string(12) "activiteiten"
["posts_per_page"]=>
int(-1)
["order"]=>
string(3) "ASC"
["orderby"]=>
string(14) "meta_value_num"
["meta_query"]=>
array(3) {
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "locatie"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "grem"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(10) "start_date"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "19700101"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(1) "="
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "DATE"
  }
}
["tax_query"]=>
array(2) {
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(9) "eventtype"
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "slug"
    ["terms"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["operator"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
  }
}
["error"]=>
string(0) ""
["m"]=>
string(0) ""
["p"]=>
int(0)
["post_parent"]=>
string(0) ""
["subpost"]=>
string(0) ""
["subpost_id"]=>
string(0) ""
["attachment"]=>
string(0) ""
["attachment_id"]=>
int(0)
["name"]=>
string(0) ""
["pagename"]=>
string(0) ""
["page_id"]=>
int(0)
["second"]=>
string(0) ""
["minute"]=>
string(0) ""
["hour"]=>
string(0) ""
["day"]=>
int(0)
["monthnum"]=>
int(0)
["year"]=>
int(0)
["w"]=>
int(0)
["category_name"]=>
string(0) ""
["tag"]=>
string(0) ""
["cat"]=>
string(0) ""
["tag_id"]=>
string(0) ""
["author"]=>
string(0) ""
["author_name"]=>
string(0) ""
["feed"]=>
string(0) ""
["tb"]=>
string(0) ""
["paged"]=>
int(0)
["meta_key"]=>
string(0) ""
["meta_value"]=>
string(0) ""
["preview"]=>
string(0) ""
["s"]=>
string(0) ""
["sentence"]=>
string(0) ""
["title"]=>
string(0) ""
["fields"]=>
string(0) ""
["menu_order"]=>
string(0) ""
["embed"]=>
string(0) ""
["category__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["category__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["category__and"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post_name__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag__and"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag_slug__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["tag_slug__and"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post_parent__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post_parent__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["author__in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["author__not_in"]=>
array(0) {
}
["search_columns"]=>
array(0) {
}
["ignore_sticky_posts"]=>
bool(false)
["suppress_filters"]=>
bool(false)
["cache_results"]=>
bool(true)
["update_post_term_cache"]=>
bool(true)
["update_menu_item_cache"]=>
bool(false)
["lazy_load_term_meta"]=>
bool(true)
["update_post_meta_cache"]=>
bool(true)
["nopaging"]=>
bool(true)
["comments_per_page"]=>
string(2) "50"
["no_found_rows"]=>
bool(false)
}
["tax_query"]=>
object(WP_Tax_Query)#16583 (6) {
["queries"]=>
array(2) {
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(9) "eventtype"
    ["terms"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "slug"
    ["operator"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["include_children"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
["relation"]=>
string(3) "AND"
["table_aliases":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["queried_terms"]=>
array(1) {
  ["eventtype"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["terms"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["field"]=>
    string(4) "slug"
  }
}
["primary_table"]=>
string(8) "wp_posts"
["primary_id_column"]=>
string(2) "ID"
}
["meta_query"]=>
object(WP_Meta_Query)#16582 (9) {
["queries"]=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "locatie"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "grem"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(10) "start_date"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "19700101"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(1) "="
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "DATE"
  }
  ["relation"]=>
  string(3) "AND"
}
["relation"]=>
string(3) "AND"
["meta_table"]=>
string(11) "wp_postmeta"
["meta_id_column"]=>
string(7) "post_id"
["primary_table"]=>
string(8) "wp_posts"
["primary_id_column"]=>
string(2) "ID"
["table_aliases":protected]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "wp_postmeta"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "mt1"
}
["clauses":protected]=>
array(2) {
  ["wp_postmeta"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "locatie"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "grem"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
    ["compare_key"]=>
    string(1) "="
    ["alias"]=>
    string(11) "wp_postmeta"
    ["cast"]=>
    string(4) "CHAR"
  }
  ["mt1"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(10) "start_date"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "19700101"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(1) "="
    ["type"]=>
    string(4) "DATE"
    ["compare_key"]=>
    string(1) "="
    ["alias"]=>
    string(3) "mt1"
    ["cast"]=>
    string(4) "DATE"
  }
}
["has_or_relation":protected]=>
bool(false)
}
["date_query"]=>
bool(false)
["request"]=>
string(845) "
        SELECT   wp_posts.*
        FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
        WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
0 = 1
) AND ( 
( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'locatie' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{32da730d7dff16f9a8a6018089c2f551df96718b2558a8935f0dea7f6bcc3c17}grem{32da730d7dff16f9a8a6018089c2f551df96718b2558a8935f0dea7f6bcc3c17}' )
AND 
( mt1.meta_key = 'start_date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) = '19700101' )
) AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'activiteiten' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')))
        GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
        ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC
"
["posts"]=>
array(0) {
}
["post_count"]=>
int(0)
["current_post"]=>
int(-1)
["before_loop"]=>
bool(true)
["in_the_loop"]=>
bool(false)
["comment_count"]=>
int(0)
["current_comment"]=>
int(-1)
["found_posts"]=>
int(0)
["max_num_pages"]=>
int(0)
["max_num_comment_pages"]=>
int(0)
["is_single"]=>
bool(false)
["is_preview"]=>
bool(false)
["is_page"]=>
bool(false)
["is_archive"]=>
bool(true)
["is_date"]=>
bool(false)
["is_year"]=>
bool(false)
["is_month"]=>
bool(false)
["is_day"]=>
bool(false)
["is_time"]=>
bool(false)
["is_author"]=>
bool(false)
["is_category"]=>
bool(false)
["is_tag"]=>
bool(false)
["is_tax"]=>
bool(true)
["is_search"]=>
bool(false)
["is_feed"]=>
bool(false)
["is_comment_feed"]=>
bool(false)
["is_trackback"]=>
bool(false)
["is_home"]=>
bool(false)
["is_privacy_policy"]=>
bool(false)
["is_404"]=>
bool(false)
["is_embed"]=>
bool(false)
["is_paged"]=>
bool(false)
["is_admin"]=>
bool(true)
["is_attachment"]=>
bool(false)
["is_singular"]=>
bool(false)
["is_robots"]=>
bool(false)
["is_favicon"]=>
bool(false)
["is_posts_page"]=>
bool(false)
["is_post_type_archive"]=>
bool(false)
["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=>
string(32) "7c12bc011734d561a7fdf7f91b652543"
["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=>
bool(false)
["thumbnails_cached"]=>
bool(false)
["allow_query_attachment_by_filename":protected]=>
bool(false)
["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=>
NULL
["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(15) "query_vars_hash"
[1]=>
string(18) "query_vars_changed"
}
["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(16) "init_query_flags"
[1]=>
string(15) "parse_tax_query"
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain if your `date('Ymd', strtotime($date))` formatting is going to work with your `'type' => 'DATE'` comparison.  I've always found WP's dates to be too stringent and so I save all of my dates as epoch date/times and then just run numerical comparisons.

Comment: I use ```date('Ymd)``` to query all posts with start_date today or somewhere in the future and that works fine, what would make the difference to it won't work wit ```strtotime($date)``` when I try to do the same while accessing a variable?

Comment: If the date and location are working without the taxonomy then the date isn't the issue, in that case it may just be that the merging of the queries is the issue.  Are you able to `var_dump()` the full query so we can see how the `$meta_query` and `$tax_query` are structured?  Instead of `echo $response;` just use `var_dump($ajaxposts)`.

Comment: @TonyDjukic I added the dump information

Comment: So from that `var_dump()` it doesn't look as though anything is being passed into the `tax_query()`.  So it may not be working simply because it's not receiving any info.